# How to multiply two arrays element-wise

Tags: swift

I need to multiply an array by another array element-wise, just like the Hadamard product of vectors in math. For example:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [2,3,4,5]
C = A*B = [2,6,12,20]
```

I can't even figure out the code, I've tried doing so element by element but this seems too messy of a solution for me, any ideas?

Comment: Actually that is not how vectors (or matrices) are usually multiplied :)

Answer (score 29):

"Zipping" the two arrays gives a sequence of tuples `(a_i, b_i)`
which can then be multiplied element-wise:

```
let A = [1,2,3,4]
let B = [2,3,4,5]

let C = zip(A, B).map { $0 * $1 }

print(C) // [2, 6, 12, 20]
```

(If the arrays have different length then `zip` silently ignores the extra elements of the longer array.)

As @appzYourLife correctly said, you can also pass the multiplication
operator directly as an argument to `map` instead of a closure expression:

```
let C = zip(A, B).map(*)
```

Comment: Just a very tiny refinement: `map { $0 * $1 }` can become `map(*)`

Comment: how can we get the total sum of the C array?

Comment: @GurjitSingh: `let sum = C.reduce(0, +)`

Answer (score 6):

### Single Instruction Multiple Data

If your vectors have exactly 4 components you can use the superfast `simd` (*Single Instruction Multiple Data*) instructions provided by iOS.

It uses the CPU  to perform parallel computations.

Given 2 vectors of 4 components of `Int32`

```
import simd

let a = int4(1, 2, 3, 4)
let b = int4(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

you can multiply each component

```
let res = a &* b // int4(2, 6, 12, 20)
```

> As noted by *Martin R* , array of `float(s)` or of `double(s)` are provided as well by the `simd` module.

Comment: Good idea! (`float4`s and `double4`s can be multiplied as well.)

Answer (score 6):

Accelerate framework

For the topic of vector multiplication, another alternative (in addition to [the neat `simd` covered by @appzYourLife's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39724903/4573247)) is making use of the [Accelerate framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate). In this case, specifically the [vDSP methods](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/1652565-vdsp) `vDSP_vmul` and `vDSP_vmuld`,

> ```
> func vDSP_vmul(UnsafePointer<Float>, vDSP_Stride, 
>                UnsafePointer<Float>, vDSP_Stride, 
>                UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, vDSP_Stride, vDSP_Length)
>
> func vDSP_vmulD(UnsafePointer<Double>, vDSP_Stride, 
>                 UnsafePointer<Double>, vDSP_Stride, 
>                 UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>, vDSP_Stride, vDSP_Length)
> ```

E.g., the latter used for element-by-element multiplication of two vectors of `Double` values:

```
import Accelerate

let a = [1.5, 2.5, 16.5, 7.5, 3.0]
let b = [3.0, 4.5, 0.25, 3.5, 6.25]
var result = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: a.count)

if a.count == b.count {
    vDSP_vmulD(a, 1, b, 1, &result, 1, vDSP_Length(a.count))
    print(result) // [4.5, 11.25, 4.125, 26.25, 18.75]
}
```

Note that using Accelerate is not as user friendly and safe as the alternative methods, as the vector arguments to `vDSP_vmulD` are captured as unsafe pointers (`UnsafePointer<Double>`), and that it's our responsibility to make sure that the input vectors are of same length, as well as the result vector being properly allocated prior to the vector multiplication by `vDSP_vmulD`.

Comment: And so an initially "simple" question becomes more and more interesting ...

Comment: @MartinR: Indeed. Even more surprising is that, as far as I can tell, this seemingly commonly-asked question has not been asked before (or maybe it has, but is hidden beneath some obscure title).

Comment: how would this go with surge?

Comment: @DaveKliman I haven't used Surge myself, but as I've understood it's simply a well-written wrapper for Accelerate, so performance-wise Surge should be comparable to the above, but with a (possibly) user-friendlier API.

Comment: now if only I could figure out how to properly install surge into an Xcode project. feel free to point me in the right direction? swift package manager maybe?

Comment: @DaveKliman since I haven't used it myself, I can't really say. At first glance, it doesn't seem to be a pod for it (otherwise Cocoapods is quite approachable for 3rd party libs), but I would probably just clone the repo and make use of [the `/Source` folder](https://github.com/mattt/Surge/tree/master/Source).

Comment: Is there a way to do that and still benefit from the kind of automatic updates that using it as a dependency would offer?

Comment: @DaveKliman since it doesn't seem to be a pod or available via carthage, I believe no. I would probably just try to use accelerate directly: it has a slight learning threahold, but mostly it's just different syntax compared to the Swift-sugared Surge.

Answer (score 3):

With Swift 5, you can use one of the following ways in order to solve you problem.

### Using [SIMD vector types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/numbers_and_basic_values/simd_vector_types)

The following Playground sample code shows an element-wise multiplication using [`SIMD4`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/simd4):

```
let vector1 = SIMD4(1, 2, 3, 4)
let vector2 = SIMD4(2, 3, 4, 5)

let vector3 = vector1 &* vector2
print(vector3) // prints: SIMD4<Int>(2, 6, 12, 20)
```

Note that [`SIMD`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/simd) protocol conforms to [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral). Therefore, you can initialize your vector using an array literal:

```
var vector1: SIMD4 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let vector2: SIMD4 = [2, 3, 4, 5]

vector1 &*= vector2
print(vector1) // prints: SIMD4<Int>(2, 6, 12, 20)
```

### Using a custom type that conforms to [`Numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) and [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) protocols

You can build your own custom type that conforms to `Numeric` and `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`. The following Playground sample code shows how to implement and use it:

```
struct Vector {
    let x, y: Int

    init(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}
```

```
extension Vector: AdditiveArithmetic {
    static var zero: Vector {
        return Vector(0, 0)
    }

    static func +(lhs: Vector, rhs: Vector) -> Vector {
        return Vector(lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y)
    }

    static func +=(lhs: inout Vector, rhs: Vector) {
        lhs = lhs + rhs
    }

    static func -(lhs: Vector, rhs: Vector) -> Vector {
        return Vector(lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y)
    }

    static func -=(lhs: inout Vector, rhs: Vector) {
        lhs = lhs - rhs
    }
}
```

```
extension Vector: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        x = value
        y = value
    }
}
```

```
import Darwin

extension Vector: Numeric {
    var magnitude: Int {
        // Implement according to your needs
        return Int(Darwin.sqrt(Double(x * x + y * y)))
    }

    init?<T>(exactly source: T) where T : BinaryInteger {
        guard let source = source as? Int else  {
            return nil
        }
        x = source
        y = source
    }

    static func *(lhs: Vector, rhs: Vector) -> Vector {
        return Vector(lhs.x * rhs.x, lhs.y * rhs.y)
    }

    static func *=(lhs: inout Vector, rhs: Vector) {
        lhs = lhs * rhs
    }
}
```

```
extension Vector: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Int...) {
        assert(elements.count == 2, "arrayLiteral should have exactly 2 elements")
        self.x = elements[0]
        self.y = elements[1]
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let vector1 = Vector(1, 2)
let vector2 = Vector(2, 3)

let vector3 = vector1 * vector2
print(vector3) // prints: Vector(x: 2, y: 6)
```

```
let vector1: Vector = [1, 2]
let vector2: Vector = [2, 3]

let vector3 = vector1 * vector2
print(vector3) // prints: Vector(x: 2, y: 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let A = [1,2,3,4]
 let B = [2,3,4,5]
 var C = [Int]()

 A.enumerated().forEach{ index, value in
     return C.append(value * B[index])
 }
```

Comment: This code will crash if `A` has more elements than `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming arrays of Double or Float values of arbitrary but the same length:

```
import Accelerate
...
let a: [Float] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let b: [Float] = [5, 6, 7, 8]
let c = vDSP.multiply(a, b)
```