# Creating an array in Swift by applying binary operation to all elements of two other arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, elementwise-operations

Is there a concise way in Swift of creating an array by applying a binary operation on the elements of two other arrays?

For example:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = [4, 5, 6]
let c = (0..<3).map{a[$0]+b[$0]} // c = [5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: "Almost" duplicate (same question for multiplication instead of addition) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724115/swift-how-to-multiply-array-by-array-math-vector-by-vector.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use [zip](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541125-zip) to combine the elements, you can refer to `+` with just `+`:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = [4, 5, 6]    
let c = zip(a, b).map(+)  // [5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

You can use `indices` like this:

```
for index in a.indices{
    sum.append(a[index] + b[index])
}
print(sum)// [5, 7, 9]
```

<sub>(Thanks to Alexander's comment this is better, because we don't have to deal with the `element` itself and we just deal with the `index`)</sub>

**Old answer:**

you can enumerate to get the index:

```
var sum = [Int]()
for (index, _) in a.enumerated(){
    sum.append(a[index] + b[index])
}
print(sum)// [5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: There's no reason to be using `enumerated` if you're only interested in the index or the element, but not both. Otherwise, just use `a.indices`