# how to add two array with index values in swift?

Tags: swift

If there are two arrays created in swift like this:

```
var a:[String] = ["1", "2", "3"]

var b:[String] = ["A","B","C"]
```

How can they be merged to ["1-A","2-B","3-C"]?

Comment: Is the Second array and the resultant array a string array?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724115/swift-how-to-multiply-array-by-array-math-vector-by-vector.

Comment: But you should clarify your question. Are A, B, C given numbers? Is the expected result an array of differences, or an array of strings?

Comment: updated my questions plz check

Comment: this `var b:[CGFloat]` should be `var b:[String]` or omit `:[String]`

Comment: sorry guys..plz check latest one

Comment: `zip(a, b).map { $0 + "-" + $1 }`

Comment: `a` can be `[String]` or `[Int]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = ["A","B","C"]
let res = zip(a, b).map { "\($0)-\($1)" } 
print(res)
```