# Is there an easy way to compute difference between two arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to compute the difference between the values in two arrays in Swift. I want to subtract values at each index between two arrays.

I tried doing the following:

```
var array1 : [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var array2 : [Double] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

var result = array2 - array1
```

Expected answer:

> result = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

I get the following error message:

> Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two '[Double]' operands

The following worked:

```
var array1 : [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var array2 : [Double] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

let velocity = (0..<5).map { array2[$0] - array1[$0] }
print(velocity)
```

I wanted to understand if there is an efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt works quite well. In general, you would need to check which array has the fewer elements (just in case):

```
(0..<(min(array1.count, array2.count))).map { array2[$0] - array1[$0] }
```

Or, as Connor mentioned in their answer, use `zip`, which handles this comparison of array lengths for you.

```
zip(lhs, rhs).map { $0.0 - $0.1 }
```

You can go one step further and overload the `-` operator to achieve the syntax you wanted (`array1 - array2`):

```
func -<T: Numeric>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> [T] {
    return zip(lhs, rhs).map(-)
}

// usage:
print([1,2,3] - [0, 1, 2])
```

But do note that, to other people, it might be quite unclear what an array “minus” another array means.

Comment: I would not overload `-` for arrays: It might then be tempting to overload  `+` as well, and then `let cArray = aArray + bArray` becomes ambiguous. Just my 2 ct.

Comment: @MartinR I mentioned it only because I saw OP attempt that syntax. It might make more sense to OP’s mind, but I guess not for everyone else...

Comment: @MartinR two more cents: `var result = array1; catlas_daxpby(Int32(array2.count), 1, &array2, 1, -1, &result, 1)` is probably faster with longer arrays

Comment: @ielyamani: Using the Accelerate framework was also suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39727843/1187415)  from the duplicate target. For differences that would be [vDSP_vsub](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449900-vdsp_vsub) (or its double precision variant).

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the 2 arrays together to get pairs of elements, and then `map` over them:

```
let result = zip(array1, array2).map { $0 - $1 }
```

Note that, with this method, if one array has more elements than the other, those extra elements will be ignored.

Comment: You'll want to swap the two arrays and you can just use `-`: `let result = zip(array2, array1).map(-)`